# Trigger workflow on outbound email

Tags: workflow

How can I trigger a workflow (related to Opportunity object) when an email (using a template) is sent from Opportunity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a workflow, certain criteria have to meet on the concerned object, so maybe you can create a custom field say isEmailSent and mark it true when the email is being sent and have the workflow criteria set to check for this field.

**Editing the answer as per the comments - 11/02**

Ahhh, I see. I dont think its possible via standard functionality. However, a workaround could be to create a custom button on Opportunity detail page and then check off the checkbox and redirect it to the 'Send an Email' standard page utilizing its url. You can also hide the standard button so that the users do not click on it.

Comment: I am aware of this, I was hoping for something a little more automated incase the user forgets to check the tickbox.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I dont think its possible via standard functionality. However, a workaround could be to create a custom button on Opportunity detail page and then check off the checkbox and redirect it to the 'Send an Email' standard page utilizing its url. You can also hide the standard button so that the users do not click on it.

Comment: Yes I was aware of this function, I was trying to stay away from custom code but it looks like this is the only option. Please convert to answer.